# Setting properties, and storing them in a file

Tags: java, oop, file-io

I have a class, which handles a given a "configuration file" from the package. Since I only need to handle simple key/value pairs, I thought that working with `Properties` would be OK.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ConfigFile {

    private Properties appProps = new Properties();
    private String filename;
    private InputStream in;

    public ConfigFile(String file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        this.filename = file;
        in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(this.filename);
        appProps.load(in);
        in.close();
    }

    public String getProp(String key) {
        return appProps.getProperty(key);
    }

}
```

Now, I would like to make a `setProp(String key, String value)` method, which - obviously - sets the given property, and saves it to the same file it's read from. I just can't seem to figure out how to do that. I imagine I'm going to need to call `appProps.setProperty(key, value)` and then do some kind of magic using `OutputStream`, but I'm stuck with that. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When would you like to update the properties file? On each update of `appProps` or when the application shuts down or at some other update interval?

Comment: On each update of `appProps`, I think. It's probably not the most resource-efficient way, but it wouldn't be used too many times anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        Properties prop = new Properties();

    try (FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("config.properties"))
    {
        //set the properties value
        prop.setProperty("database", "localhost");
        prop.setProperty("dbuser", "mkyong");
        prop.setProperty("dbpassword", "password");

        //save properties to project root folder
        prop.store(os, null);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This should explain everything, if not feel free to ask.

Comment: Do not use a `FileOutputStream` like that. It will leak.

Comment: Okay you're right I will edit that. Just checked the code and indeed, the stream just gets flushed but not closed. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Such functionality of **auto-saving** is not provided directly within the `Properties` class, but you could compose existing functionality. You would have to implement this composition yourself, either by subclassing `Properties` and implementing a new method or by adding a utility method. If you are not interested in the existing properties, you could write code like that:

```
void update(String file, String key, String value) throws IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(file));
    try {
    properties.load(is);
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
    properties.setProperty(key, value);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(file));
    try {
      properties.store(os);
    } finally {
      os.close();
    }
}
```